# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\server\htdocs\skyk\admin\manage-work.php on line 265

Tags: php

i want to upload multiple file using on single input with the name of "subfile".

here is the php code .

```
  $uploads_dir = "work/";
foreach ($_FILES["subfile"]["name"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["subfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["subfile"]["name"][$key];

  $pic12="work/";

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
 // $insertalbumimage=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gallery`(`image`, `albumid`) VALUES ('$pic12','$album')");

    }
}
```

i have tried `if(isset($_FILES['subfiles'])){}`

Comment: Show your form html. I have a sneaking suspicion it's because you don't have `name="subfile[]"`

Comment: show `print_r($_FILES);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading multiple files you need to do the following:

- Input name must be be defined as an array i.e. name="inputName[]"
- Input element must have multiple="multiple" or just multiple
- In your PHP file use the syntax "$_FILES['inputElemName']['param'][index]"
- Look for empty file names and paths, the array might contain empty strings

here is a down and dirty example (showing just relevant code)

```
HTML:

<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />

PHP:



//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

to insure you have the right data type provided for foreach you may check the variable's data type first:

```
if(!empty($_FILES["subfile"]["name"]) && is_array($_FILES["subfile"]["name"])){
   foreach ($_FILES["subfile"]["name"] as $key => $error) {
       //etc ...............
   }
}
```

This way you'll be sure that you'll prevent the error you've got